# Limitar la cantidad de decimales

Tags: java, poo, double

Si quiero introducir el precio $6.00 ¿Cómo hago para limitar la cantidad de decimales?

Usando:

```
 dts.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(txtprecioExamen.getText()));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use un [DecimalFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
double numero = 0.9999999999999;
DecimalFormat numeroFormateado = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(numeroFormateado.format(numero));
```

Entonces basado en su código sería algo como esto:

```
Double valor= Double.parseDouble(txtprecioExamen.getText());
DecimalFormat numeroFormateado = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
dts.setPrecio(numeroFormateado.format(valor));
```

Te dará "0.99". Puede agregar o restar 0 en el lado derecho para obtener más o menos decimales.

O use `'#'` a la derecha para hacer que los dígitos adicionales sean opcionales, como con `#. ##` (0.30) soltaría el 0 final para convertirse en (0.3).

> Fuente SO: [How do I limit the number of decimals printed for a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895395/8933039)

---

Otra manera de especificar la cantidad de Decimales puede ser así:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat();
formato.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); //Con esta Linea.
String textoFormateado = formato.format(su_variable);
```

Espero le sirva de algo :)

Comment: Gracias lo pondré en práctica

Comment: @Esme si la respuesta le ha resuelto el problema, considere marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: :) ¿Dónde se marca como respuesta aceptada?

Comment: @Esme Ya la has marcado como aceptada, pero de todos modos, te invito a mirar [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) ademas realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio. Saludos!